# Xamarin запись файла в внутреннее хранилище. Android

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Есть ли способ получить доступ к внутреннему хранилищу Android, на пример по пути /storage/emulated/0/Download. А то при попытке чтения или записи получаю отказ в доступе. Разрешения в манифесте посмотрел, нашел там только на sd карту.

Answer (score 0):

Да возможно. Если у Вас Андроид до 10, то достаточно добавить в манифест разрешения

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

это можно сделать и через интерфейс Visualstudio

и потом после установки дать приложению права(разрешить) в настройках доступ к хранилищу

Если у Вас 10 Андроид этого будет не достаточно. В 10  запрещен доступ в произвольные каталоги. Необходимо там же в манифесте в секции <application добавить android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true". Насколько я понял только в ручную.

Comment: Попробовал, студия не видит android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" и не дает скомпилировать

Comment: Поставил api 29, теперь студия не ругается, но все равно aссess denied